# Why doesn't RPG fit into Arqade?

Tags: discussion

Why can't RPG fit into Arqade? After all, it has an rpg tag. The way I see it, any question about an role playing game would be a game that fits in Gaming. Why isn't it merged?

Comment: I see by your profile stats that you're relatively new to this site. I suggest you look at questions on the main site, [take the tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [our entry on what's on-topic for this site](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Hopefully that'll give some useful context for why the two Stacks attract different types of expertise.

Answer (score 20):

Because Arqade is about video games and computer games, and we’re about tabletop, pen-and-paper, and live-action roleplaying. The RPG tag on Arqade applies to a genre of video game, not the games that this site is about. There is minimal overlap between expertise in one or the other, so there’s little reason to expect Arqade’s users to be able to answer questions about this site’s topic, and vice versa.

Comment: It should also be noted that the RPG genre writ large is inspired by, and often runs on internal rules based on table top games.